# $or aggregate not working in nodejs but working in mongoshell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

this is my mongoshell query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([ 
        { 
            '$match': { 
                "orderCreatedBy": ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"),
                 "submittedTo": ObjectId("5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1"),
                '$or': [
                    {'orderCreatedOn': ISODate("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z")},
                    {'orderCreatedOn': ISODate("2020-01-25T18:30:00Z")}
                ]}}]).pretty()
```

that's working as expected in mongoshell,
**now here my nodejs code:**

```
const Order = require("../model/order");
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

exports.dashboard = async (req, res, next) => {
const { submittedTo, orderCreatedBy } = req.body;

  let lastWeekDate = new Date();
  let numberOfDaysToSubtract = -6;
  lastWeekDate.setDate(lastWeekDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToSubtract);
  let date = lastWeekDate.toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T18:30:00.000Z";
  date = new Date(date);
  console.log(date) // 2020-01-25T18:30:00.000Z

  let tomorrowDate = new Date();
  tomorrowDate = tomorrowDate.setDate(tomorrowDate.getDate() + 1);
  tomorrowDate = new Date(tomorrowDate);
  tomorrowDate = tomorrowDate.toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T18:30:00.000Z";
  tomorrowDate = new Date(tomorrowDate);
  console.log(tomorrowDate) // 2020-02-01T18:30:00.000Z

  try {
    const order = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          orderCreatedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderCreatedBy),
          submittedTo: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(submittedTo),
          "$or": [
            { "orderCreatedOn": date },
            { "orderCreatedOn": tomorrowDate }
          ]
        }
      }])
        return res.status(200).json({
          order
          });
      } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
      }
    };
```

**POSTMAN BODY:** `{"orderCreatedBy":"5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1","submittedTo":"5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"}`
**POSTMAN RESPONSE:** `{"order": []}`

please have a look at it why is this not working in nodejs driver but in shell only 
here is the sample document of the orders collection

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e27f736a42d441fe8a8957d"),
    "isApproved" : false,
    "vendorOrder" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95113"),
                    "publicationCode" : "TOI",
                    "publicationName" : "Times of India",
                    "editionName" : "chennai city",
                    "productCode" : "TCE1",
                    "subscriptionCopies" : 70,
                    "tradeCopies" : 40
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95112"),
                    "publicationCode" : "ET",
                    "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
                    "editionName" : "chennai city",
                    "productCode" : "ECE1",
                    "subscriptionCopies" : 20,
                    "tradeCopies" : 100
            }
    ],
    "frequency" : "TH",
    "orderCreatedBy" : ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"),
    "submittedTo" : ObjectId("5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1"),
    "orderCreatedOn" : ISODate("2020-02-01T18:30:00Z"),
```

There are several documents **one document is also with "orderCreatedOn" : ISODate("2020-02-25T18:30:00Z") of last week** I need to show both documents, I had commented the `$or` condition then I was getting the response but the moment I uncomment the $or condition it again an empty []

Comment: Seems values are switched in Postman query `{"orderCreatedBy":"5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1","submittedTo":"5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2"}`. Should be `{"orderCreatedBy":"5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2","submittedTo":"5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1"}`

Comment: OHHH YESSS thanks very much@  Rashad Ibrahimov can you help me out in constructing its response also

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "constructing response" ?